# Create Recipe function in my app is not working(Ruby on Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models, `Chef` and `Recipe`. Now, the `create` function in my app is not working, it doesn't even redirect me to anywhere even though the function `create` has been defined, nor does it show any link when I move the cursor on the button in my app.

My code:

**/controllers/recipes_controller.rb**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @recipes=Recipe.all
    end

    def show
        @recipe=Recipe.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @recipe=Recipe.new
    end

    def create
        @recipe=Recipe.new(recipe_params)

        if @recipe.save
            flash[:notice] = "Your Recipe was created successfully ! "
            redirect_to recipes_path
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
        @recipe=Recipe.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @recipe=Recipe.find(params[:id])
        if @recipe.update!(recipe_params)
            #do something
            flash[:notice]= "Your Recipe was updated Successfully"
            redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
        else
            render :edit
        end
     end

    private

        def recipe_params
            params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :summary, :description, :picture)
        end

end
```

**/views/recipes/_form.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <h1>create a new recipe</h1>
</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="well col-md-8 col-md-offset-2>
        <%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :summary %>
        <%= f.text_field :summary %>

        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 10  %>

        <%= f.button :submit ,input_html: { class: "btn btn-success" } %>
        <% end %> 

    </div>
</div>
```

**/models/recipe.rb**

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chef
  validates :chef_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 100}
  validates :summary, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 150}
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 20, maximum: 500}
end
```

**/models/chef.rb**

```
class Chef < ApplicationRecord

has_many :recipes
has_many :likes

before_save { self.email = email.downcase}
validates :chefname, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 40}
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 105}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}
```

end

**/config/routes.rb**

```
  get 'pages/home'
  root 'pages#home'


  resources :recipes
end
```

**/assets/javascript/application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Ps:- Recently read a post where it said the problem might exist due to *jquery* being reloaded on the page twice.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Are you sure you're passing all your validations on the Recipe? Looks like if its invalid it'll re-render the current page but not change anything on the page to let you know a problem occurred. To quickly test, just add `<%= debug @recipes.errors.full_messages %>` to your `_form.html.erb` and see if that changes after you submit. (regardless, you should add something on your `_form.html.erb` that lets the user know what validation failed if it didn't save)

Comment: yes i am passing all the validations on recipe. i have tested them on TDD and they are working all fine. well, here is my error msg code  : <% if obj.errors.any? %>
<div class="row">
 <div class="alert alert-danger col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <h5>please correct the following errors:</h5>
  <ul> <% obj.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
   <li><%=msg %></li>
   <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<% end %>  this has been added to the form but it displays nothing

Comment: Since a recipe belongs_to :chef, you have to set the chef in the new action of the controller. Also, check the logs to see what happens when you press the create button.

Comment: @hashrocket nothing happens in the log when I click the create button

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a jquery error*

Rails uses `ujs` on `remote links` that is used with `ajax` protocol, not with simple `HTTP` links.

It stopped working after you created the `chef` relationship?

Seems like that your controller isn't prepared to receive a `chef_id`, and it's a `required field`.
Also, your form doesn't seem to be prepared to show this error on html, so check your terminal log, your validation error will be printed on it.

Edit. I'll try to explain better what is causing the error.

After you created the `belongs_to: chef`relationship, your `recipe` needs to be linked on some `chef`. You probably said to your app that a `chef` has many `recipes`, and that the `recipe` can't exist without a `chef`.
On your controller, you are creating a `recipe` without a `chef`.

Is `chef` a user and you are using `devise` gem?

Comment: the create action was not working from the very beginning before i added the chef model and the respective validations. everything else is working fine except the create button. nothing at all happens when i press the button.

Comment: Like @Simple Lime said, when you click on the `create`  button it's getting requested to render the `:new` action, thats why you feel like there is nothing happening. The problem is that you need to pass a `chef_id` to the recipe. `chef` is the current user logged in?

Comment: How do I  link my chef_id and the recipe in my controller ? Also I have added all the validations like you said correctly.

Comment: Also, Chef is a user model and no i am not using devise. building it through scratch using has_secure_password

Comment: If the `chef_id` is the logged in user id, you need to set a helper function like devise's `curent_user`, that returns the current user logged in data. 

I've seeen again your routes and it doesn't seem that you have a proper `login` route. 
Right now, you have a `login` on your app? If you have, there is probably some type of `SessionsController` right?

Comment: assuming i dont have a login. its just a basic app where you can create recipes. also i checked, the chef_id is linked to the recipe. i.e each recipe has a resp chef_id. the problem persists yet. please help me, i am really very confused.

Comment: Sorry for the lateness! The problem still happens?
Can you paste your `chef.rb` model?
So basically, when you register a recipe you'll select a chef for it?

Comment: thankyou for showing concern! but unfortunately the problem still persists. here i have added the chef model. please take a look. secondly, when i register a chef, i'll create recipes for it. and once again, the problem is i cannot create a chef neither a recipe via my app. but i can create them in my Rails console. also, Validations work perfect when i try them in my rails console.

Comment: Ok, the problem is still the same, your `RecipesController` isn't prepared to receive a chef...

Which command do you use when trying to create a recipe within `rails console`?

Comment: I checked my browser console. I got *uncaught RefrencError: Jquery is not defined* and *$ is not defined*

Comment: It doesn't make sense for `Recipe.create!` to work, since you are trying to create an object without any `parameters`...